# To what source type a listener is added, when implementing a weak listener? (Java)

Tags: java, listener, netbeans-platform

On [this](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/WeakListeners.html) docu about the `WeakListeners` I found that code snipped:

```
    private void registerTo(Source source) {
        listener = new Listener();
        source.addChangeListener(WeakListeners.change (listener, source));
    }

    private class Listener implements ChangeListener {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            doSomething();
        }
```

What is that source object, they are writing about? We could not find anything on google.

Comment: The source object is the object that fires the events, that you want to listen to. For example, if you want to know when a button is clicked, you register a listener for click events on the button. The button is the source. It's the button that emits the click events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What exact Interface my class must implement, or what class my class must extend from, to be able to be put as parameter in registerTo() ?

Comment: I don't think you need to implement any interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the docs you linked.
Further down it states:

> It is itself strongly referenced from the implementation of the source (e.g. from its EventListenerList)

Giving you an example of class that can be used there.
Indeed in the docs of

```
WeakListeners.change (listener, source)
```

**source is an Object** so it can be whatever you are using as an event source.
If you keep reading the doc then you'll see that:

> It tries to unregister itself from the source. This is why it needs the reference to the source for the registration. The unregistration is done using reflection, usually **looking up the method remove** of the source and calling it.

And

> This may fail if the source don't have the expected remove* method and/or if you provide wrong reference to source. In that case the weak listener instance will stay in memory and registered by the source, while the listener and observer will be freed.

So I guess you will need to use an interface with a remove method of some sort.

I went through Javadoc index and found this ([MenuBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/MenuBar.html)) as an example of what I think you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!